# Storing values in an Arraylist in Talend

Tags: arraylist, talend

I am reading a series of values from an XML iteratively,
tFlowToIterate->tFixedFlowInput.

I want to store these values in an Arraylist say, myArrlist, as myArrList[0], myArrList[1],myArrList[2] and so on.

How may I define myArrList globally in Talend so that  i can keep incrementing the index and keep appending values to my Arraylist?

Thanks.

Online

Comment: Do you really need an index ? Using ArrayList.add(E e) isn't enough ?

Answer (score 2):

Put the ArrayList into the globalMap

```
globalMap.put("myList", myArrlist);
```

and get it whenever you want it

```
ArrayList<??> ml = (ArrayList<??>)globalMap.get("myList");
```